# How to return distinct node properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (p:car)-[r]->(n:brand) where n.brandname = 'Nissan' RETURN p.sku_id
```

This query will return all 'sku_id' for the query. How can I only return unique 'sku_id' only for the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` if many Ids are the same :

```
 MATCH (p:car)-[r]->(n:brand) 
 WHERE n.brandname = 'Nissan' 
 RETURN DISTINCT p.sku_id
```

Maybe you have to be more precise :

```
MATCH (p:car {model:"Micra"})-[r]->(n:brand {brandname:"Nissan"})
RETURN DISTINCT p.sku_id
```